# Error running software installer as administrator

Tags: windows-7, administrator, .net-framework, windows-domain, ownership

I'm trying to install .NET 4.6.1 on a user's computer, but when I start the installer -- even *with* "Run as administrator" -- it fails to the message "This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object."  Information from [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978898.aspx) isn't very helpful:

> ## Error Message:
>
> This security ID may not be assigned as the owner of this object.
>
> **Explanation:**
>
> The owner of a new object must be one of the users or groups you have been given the right to assign as the owner. Typically, this is your user account and, if you are an administrator, the administrator's local group.
>
> **User Action:**
>
> Learn which users and groups you have the right to assign as owner. Then try again.

I *am* in the local Administrators group (though indirectly, through a domain group), and anyway as far as I can tell I'm not creating any "new objects" yet since the installer won't even start.

As a point of reference, I was able to install the same package on another computer within the last week or so with no trouble at all.  Why am I seeing this error now?  More importantly, what can I do to get the installer to run?

Comment: What about using the build-in administrator account to run the installer? It may fix this problem.

Comment: If this computer is connected to a domain, you being a local Administrator, does not mean anything.  You must be a domain Administrator.

Comment: @GreenYi, I was under the impression that's what "Run as administrator" did (for users with permission to do so).

Comment: @Ramhound OK, but then why wouldn't the other system have given me the same problem?  I'll check but I believe I have the same permissions on both.

Comment: Both systems are set up the same way:  I'm a member of the (domain) group UTAdmins, and UTAdmins is a member of (local) Administrators group.  Also, according to the answers [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/4d625983-9859-4e86-8760-0a08aa17c25c/), "Local administrator should be all that's needed to install software in
local boxes."  In other news:  don't know why it didn't occur to me earlier, but I suppose I could just try running the installer from an elevated Command Prompt (if it'll let me do that either).